# Who got introduced to whom first in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-case

I could not understand who got introduced to whom first in the following sentence – customer to employees or employees to customer?

> Eine weitere Regel ist, dass man zuerst dem Kunden die Mitarbeiter der eigenen Firma vorstellt, dann den Mitarbeitern den Kunden.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quick answer:

*zuerst*:

```
           (dem Kunden)     (die Mitarbeiter...) vorstellen
present  (to the customer)    (the employees)
```

Or, in plain English:

> first introduce the employees to the customer.

---

Grammar:

In German, the order of the various *objects* (here: accusative and dative) is not fixed. Both

> - (dem Kunden) (die Mitarbeiter...) vorstellen

and

> - (die Mitarbeiter...) (dem Kunden) vorstellen

works fine.

To decide what is happening in your example, you really need the grammar, that is, you need to determine in which case each element is and what case(s) [vorstellen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/vorstellen#Bedeutung4a) needs.

*((Jdm) etw/jdn) **vorstellen*** can take one or two objects, one is mandatory, one optional:

- mandatory: the party who is introduced or presented, in akkusative.
- optional: the party he/she/it is introduced to, in dative.

Examples:

> Apple stellt [sein neues Produkt] vor. -> accusative only
>   Apple stellt [der Presse] [sein neues Produkt] vor. -> dative and accusative
>   Apple stellt [sein neues Produkt] [der Presse] vor. -> accusative and dative
>   But NOT: <del>Apple stellt [der Presse] vor.</del> -> dative only doesn't work!

So in your sentence:

> ...
>   zuerst dem Kunden (-> dative) die Mitarbeiter...(-> akkusative) vorstellt,
>   dann den Mitarbeitern (-> dative) den Kunden (-> akkusative).

Comment: @Stephie Sie sind ein Engel.

Comment: @Stephie Als würde ich einem Link folgen O:-)